# I got problem when I build my maven projects | nexus server

Tags: java, maven, build, repository, nexus

I'm working on 5 big java maven projects on my company. And since more than a week I can't do any build because of a nexus server (v2 of nexus) that we use to store private artifacts. This nexus server crashes after 10 seconds.
By looking at the logs I can see that the server crashes when it has to initialize a repo called "Eclipse Oxygen" because this repo has not been registered in the core.

`org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration - Repository "Eclipse Oxygen" (repoId=eclipse-oxygen) corresponding type is not registered in Core, henc e it's maxInstace check cannot be performed: Repository type org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.Repository:p2 is unknown to Nexus Core. It is probably contributed by an old Nexus plugin. Please contact plugin developers to upgrade the p lugin, and register the new repository type(s) properly! jvm 1    | 2022-12-08 16:14:49,794+0100 ERROR [jetty-main-1]  org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication - Could not start Nexus, user configuration exception!`

But at the same time, looking in the nexus config files I can see that this repo "Eclipse oxygen" is well declared.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z863p.png)
I don't know if it's the version 2 of nexus that doesn't support anymore or if it's necessary to change some nexus configs.
Would you have a solution for me?
Thanks for your help

I haven't tried much except to do a lot of research without finding concrete solutions.
I checked if I ping the good port. I also checked if there was a network problem and it is not the case, as well as the identification information

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by adding 2 plugins. These plugins will allow the nexus application to support p2 repositorys. You have to put the plugin int the "plugins-repository" folder in sonatype-work forlder.
The first is nexus-p2-bridge, and the second is nexus-p2-repository.
They are available on maven central or you can download the .zip with this links :

wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-p2-bridge-plugin/2.14.5-02/nexus-p2-bridge-plugin-2.14.5-02-bundle.zip

wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-p2-repository-plugin/2.14.5-02/nexus-p2-repository-plugin-2.14.5-02-bundle.zip